# Apollo GraphQL React - how to query on click?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollostack

In the Apollo React docs http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#basics there are examples of fetching automatically when the component is shown, but I'd like to run a query when a button is clicked. I see an example to "re"fetch a query when a button is clicked, but I don't want it to query initially. I see there is a way to call mutations, but how do you call queries?

Comment: any ideas on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238490/pass-variable-from-input-to-grapql-search-call

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can do it by passing a reference to Apollo Client using the `withApollo` higher-order-component, as documented here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#withApollo

Then, you can call `client.query` on the passed in object, like so:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  runQuery() {
    this.props.client.query({
      query: gql`...`,
      variables: { ... },
    });
  }

  render() { ... }
}

withApollo(MyComponent);
```

Out of curiosity, what's the goal of running a query on a click event? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish the underlying goal.

Comment: i wanted to use this for a search bar

Comment: Im finding if I use this on a component which has the gql HOC on a parent, it triggers the parents componentWillReceiveProps. No idea why.
Is there a better way? perhaps redux.

Comment: This does not update the props? Why? How can I update props after the result comes in successfully?

Comment: you  can define an updateQuery function or updateQueries object in order to update the existing props

Comment: Why can be that shows this error: `Error: Network error: Could not find query inside query map.`?

Comment: Are you using some persisted queries library?

Comment: @stubailo Yes, I have disabled persisted queries and I can use it. Thanks.

Comment: @tahayk seems like updateQuery is not in client.query api, how we can archive that ?

Comment: Sounds like this should be a new question - I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. You might be able to use `client.writeQuery` though: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient\.writeQuery

Comment: Shouldn't you just fire the submit event and pass the input as props to another component which utilizes them in a query?

Comment: is there a way to get `fetchMore()` from `this.props.client.query` like what `graphql()` has under `props.data.fetchMore()`?

Comment: any ideas on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238490/pass-variable-from-input-to-grapql-search-call

Comment: In apollo 2.1 you can user <ApolloConsumer /> component https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#apollo-consumer... Also this ---> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query

Answer (score 27):

As of version 3.0, you can do this in two ways now.

### `client.query`

The first way is to call `ApolloClient`'s `query` method. This returns a Promise that will resolve to the query's result. You can get a reference to the client by using the [withApollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/#withapollocomponent) HOC:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    const { data } = await this.props.client.query({
      query: gql`...`,
      variables: { ... },
    })
    ...
  }
  ...
}

withApollo(MyComponent)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [ApolloConsumer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-common/#apolloconsumer) to get the client:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <ApolloConsumer>
    {client => {
      ...
    }
  </ApolloConsumer>
)
```

or the [useApolloClient](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#useapolloclient) hook:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const client = useApolloClient()
  ...
}
```

### `useLazyQuery`

The second way is to use the [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#uselazyquery) hook:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [runQuery, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(gql`...`)
  const handleClick = () => runQuery({ variables: { ... } })
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hooks are headache when you need handle subscriptions. Potential of making mistakes and open too many subscription channels on the server is too high! 
```useMemo``` will help but ```subscribeToMore``` is so dangerous :)))

Comment: useLazyQuery is just what we need for immediate load. Thanks.

Comment: I have to use `useApolloClient ` because I have a list of posts and each row of the list has an edit button. I want to get post data by its id and show data in a modal when I click on edit button. I tested `useLazyQuery` it doesn't get a post data again. I mean For the second and third time, I can not do this without refresh the page.

Comment: @FullOfStack you should add argument `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` in your `useLazyQuery`