# GraphQL _ Apollo-client - pass guery variables directly in component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to pass my GraphQL queries's variables directly in my React component.

So far I have tried to pass it :

- directly in this.props.mutate
- in client.props
- in my parent component as a < parentProps variables={props} />
- vie React.clone
- in client.query

None of them works, maybe I have forget something.

Currently I have to hardcode it in the options but it privates me of the possibility to dynamically code it :

```
export default graphql(fetchRecipe, 
        {options: (props) => ({ 
            variables: {  }
        })})(Displayer);
```

*** Workaround try but fails: the vanishing pattern as following :***

```
import {...} 

var property; // just declare your property

class YourClass extends Component { 

property = newValue // your property is now available on the Component's scope, 
                    // allowing you to code it dynamically

render(){ {...}

}

export default graphql(query, 
        {options: (props) => ({ 
            variables: { property } // hence pass the value you want in your graphql options's property
        })})(YourClass);
```

So I still search how to pass it directly in component, Any hint would be great,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're probably (?) looking for graphQL usage from `inside of components`. It's possible with `<Query />` and `<Mutation />` components. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query can be suitable, too.

It has some drawbacks - composing many queries and mutations is far easier with `graphql()`.

Comment: It could be interesting yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814853/apollo-graphql-react-how-to-query-on-click

Answer (score 0):

Redux comes at hand and prove again its awesomness.

I have simply to pass the property in my Redux's state. Then, I pass the property in the variable option direclty vie the ownProps property. Hence, my state can reach the query. I will appreciate if it allow me to dynamically refetch my data now.

Here my reduxContainer.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
    return {
    property: state
    }
}
const yourContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(YourReactComponent)
export default yourContainer
```

Then, the state's connected query:

```
export default graphql(YourQuery, 
        {options(ownProps) {
            return {
              variables: { property : ownProps.property}
            }
}})(YourReactComponent);
```